# Rails - Select only Certain Info on Joined Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, where-clause

There is a Game table.  Then a Score table which holds scores associated with a game.  Each game will hold various scores for the various periods of a game, i.e. a score for the first quarter, a score for the second quarter...

```
games = Game.with_league(:nba)
        .where('date > ?', Date.new(2015,10,1))
        .joins(:scores)
```

This loads up every score associated with a game.  To make the query go faster I want to make it select only scores where the period is the 2nd quarter (which is all I need).  If I chain this onto the code above

```
.where("scores.period = ?", 1) #in my DB 1 = 2nd quarter
```

it doesn't get the results I want.  It still returns every score associated with the game.  It seems to select all games where there exists a score for the 2nd quarter.  How do I do this?

Comment: Show us the generated SQL query from your console. Might help see the problem